# Fresh install 21.04 - No sound

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Brand new to linux. I did my first fresh install yesterday on a fully formatted hard drive. I don't seem to be able to get my sound working.

I have my speakers plugged directly into my mobo (onboard sound), and my headphones plugged into my PCI sound card (Soundblaster Z). Neither of them are working.

The majority of the tutorials online suggest setting the sound driver indexing, but I don't think that's necessarily the issue. I ran 'alsamixer 0', used F6 to choose sound cards, and I went through each one listening for sound but heard absolutely nothing.

```
snd_hda_intel          53248  7
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         147456  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
snd_hda_core           94208  6 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
snd_pcm               118784  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_ca0132,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                    94208  28 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_ca0132,snd_rawmidi
benjamin@Benja-PC:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio [8086:a2f0]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series PCH HD Audio [1462:da62]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 HD Audio Controller [10de:10f8] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] TU104 HD Audio Controller [1462:373e]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
05:00.0 Audio device [0403]: Creative Labs Sound Core3D [Sound Blaster Recon3D / Z-Series] [1102:0012] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Creative Labs SB1570 SB Audigy Fx [1102:0010]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

From the command above, I can see that I have kernal drivers for snd_hda_intel.

Fairly certain my cards are being seen (Not sure why NVidia is there).

```
benjamin@Benja-PC:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf520000 irq 149
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xdf080000 irq 17
 2 [Creative       ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Creative
                      HDA Creative at 0xdf304000 irq 17
```

I can see the volume within pavucontrol:

[image]

I have my headphones set as output device in sound settings but still can't hear anything. I've tried with my speakers too, to no avail.

I'm brand new to linux. I set up my partitions manually, with /boot, swap, efi system partition and root all on my M2 drive, and /home taking up the full space on my SSD. Unsure if this would have an effect on how ubuntu originally sets up the audio config.

so any help would be greatly appreciated.